# Is national/regional stage filing requires PCT application as filed?

Tags: pct

I have a PCT application that has around 250 claims. It's an omnibus application that covers multiple inventions. Listed all claims just for provisional protection.

If I go for national/regional stage, say EPO for example, do I have to file the EPO application using my PCT application as exactly filed?

I mean do I have to pay fees for all 250 claims when entering EPO?  Or I can add/remove claims before entering national/regional stage?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No - you can amend the claims as you enter the EPO and other places.

Comment: Concise, but right to the point. Thanks. :-)

Comment: @Giri You are to indicate which claims you want to have in your application upon entering into the European regional phase, this means that you can file a new claim set, and you better do that because in Europe there are claim fees for each claim in excess of 15 and said fees are not cheap at all, in fact the fees are even more expensive after claim number 50.

Comment: @theEuropeist Thanks for the info. really helpful.